Why can’t I remove a secure UITextField that I added as a subview to protect against screen capture in my custom UIView extension?
I’m working on a custom UIView extension in Swift that adds a UITextField with isSecureTextEntry = true as a subview to prevent screen capture. The UITextField is added successfully, and I can confirm this through debug prints. However, when I try to remove this UITextField using a method in the same extension, the UITextField is never found, and thus it is never removed. My debug prints confirm that the method responsible for removal never enters the condition where the UITextField should be found and removed.
I’ve double-checked that the UITextField is assigned the correct tag and that the view hierarchy seems correct. Despite this, the viewWithTag method doesn’t seem to find the UITextField when attempting to remove it.
Here’s a simplified version of the code:
extension UIView {

private struct Constants {
    static var secureTextFieldTag: Int { 54321 }
}

func setScreenCaptureProtection() {
    if viewWithTag(Constants.secureTextFieldTag) is UITextField {
        return
    }
    
    guard superview != nil else {
        for subview in subviews {
            subview.setScreenCaptureProtection()
        }
        return
    }
    
    let secureTextField = UITextField()
    secureTextField.backgroundColor = .clear
    secureTextField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    secureTextField.tag = Constants.secureTextFieldTag
    secureTextField.isSecureTextEntry = true
    insertSubview(secureTextField, at: 0)
    secureTextField.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    layer.superlayer?.addSublayer(secureTextField.layer)
    secureTextField.layer.sublayers?.last?.addSublayer(layer)
    secureTextField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    secureTextField.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    secureTextField.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    secureTextField.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
}

func removeScreenCaptureProtection() {
    if let secureTextField = viewWithTag(Constants.secureTextFieldTag) as? UITextField {
        secureTextField.removeFromSuperview()
    } else {
        for subview in subviews {
            subview.removeScreenCaptureProtection()
        }
    }
}}

Thanks for your help!.

the main problem is you are setting tag as same for all views which is wrong... one question, when you will call setScreenCaptureProtection?

in the viewWillAppear, beacuse i need only activate the setScreenCaptureProtection in some views. the problem is if i remove "layer.superlayer?.addSublayer(secureTextField.layer)
secureTextField.layer.sublayers?.last?.addSublayer(layer)", the setScreenCaptureProtection does not work.

Okay. I got now... For test can you check with 1 label and see if its working or not... if working, then give different tag numbers.. don't duplicate tag numbers...
